# redirect using a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, redirect

this form (views/workers/_form.html.erb) redirects me to the index of tasksadmins, after I push the 'create tasksadmin' button.

I want it to redirect me to "workers/index" and change the button to 'update the task'.

how can I do that please?

```
<%= form_for(@tasksadmin) do |f| %>
  <% if @tasksadmin.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@tasksadmin.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this tasksadmin from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @tasksadmin.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :admin_mail, :value => @tasksadmin.admin_mail %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :worker_mail, :value => @worker_mail %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :task, :value => @tasksadmin.task %>


<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :done %><br />
  <%= f.check_box :done %>
</div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**and this is my workers_controller**:

```
class WorkersController < ApplicationController
  # GET /workers
  # GET /workers.json
  def index
    @tasks_worker = Tasksadmin.where(:worker_mail => "alon.shmiel@gmail.com")

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @workers }
    end
  end

  # GET /workers/1
  # GET /workers/1.json
  def show
    @task_worker = Tasksadmin.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @worker }
    end
  end

  # GET /workers/new
  # GET /workers/new.json
  def new
    @worker = Worker.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @worker }
    end
  end

  # GET /workers/1/edit
  def edit
    @tasksadmin = Tasksadmin.find(params[:id])
    @worker_mail = "alon.shmiel@gmail.com"

  end

  # POST /workers
  # POST /workers.json
  def create
    @worker = Worker.new(params[:worker])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @worker.save
        format.html { redirect_to "@worker", notice: 'Worker was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @worker, status: :created, location: @worker }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @worker.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /workers/1
  # PUT /workers/1.json
  def update
    @worker = Tasksadmin.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @worker.update_attributes(params[:worker])
        format.html { render action: "index", notice: 'Worker was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @worker.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /workers/1
  # DELETE /workers/1.json
  def destroy
    @worker = Tasksadmin.find(params[:id])
    @worker.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render action: "index" }
      format.json { render json: @worker }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Redirection happens *after* form processing; change your controller code.

Comment: thank you, in def update? and what's about the button?

Comment: Weird how in your controller you sometimes write `Worker` and sometimes `Tasksadmin`. I would find that very confusing. Shouldn't it all be just `Worker`s ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your controller, you have to redirect to the appropriate path like so:

```
def update
  redirect_to "workers/index"
end
```

I would suggest using path helpers so if you have your routes set up as resources, you can do this:

```
redirect_to workers_path
```

As for changing the the button text, just change it to:

```
f.submit("update the task")
```

Comment: thank you. the button is changed, but it still redirect me to the show of: http://localhost:3000/tasksadmins/8

I tried:   def update
    @worker = Tasksadmin.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @worker.update_attributes(params[:worker])
        redirect_to "workers/index"
      else
        redirect_to "edit"
      end
    end
  end

Comment: I think that should work unless maybe your form submission is invalid in which case you would be redirected to the edit page.  Try redirect_to :action => 'index'

Comment: no, it doesn't work.. but thank you! I set your answer as my accepted answer. thank you very much! :]

Comment: Okay, get rid of the respond_to block.  So just write: if @worker.update_attributes(params[:worker])
  redirect_to "index"
end

Answer (score 0):

You create a form for an object `@tasksadmin`, which in your `WorkersController#edit` is set as follows:

```
@tasksadmin = Tasksadmin.find(params[:id]
```

This means that that parameter contains an object of class `Tasksadmin`, if you let rails build the path for the a `Tasksadmin`, it will send you to the `TasksadminsController#update`, and that is why your code does not work. You never get to the `WorkersController#update`. Check your logs to verify that.

Let me be very clear about this: you should not edit `Tasksadmin` objects in the `WorkersController`.

I do not understand why you would do that.